# Surefire only reports first test suite from module to RunListener

Tags: junit, teamcity, listener, maven-surefire-plugin

So I have a TeamCity and JUnit tests, and I want to write a `RunListener` to [notify TeamCity in real-time about running tests](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/11226/make-teamcity-see-test-results-in-real-time-using-maven-junit-4-and-surefire) - TeamCity only supports batched test reporting for JUnit out of box.

I have several suites, annotated with `@RunWith(Suite.class)` for logical grouping of tests.  TeamCity shows tests grouped by suite correctly. However, my problem is that Surefire will only call `RunListener.testRunStarted` once, with both suites' names in description (but no way to attribute tests to either one).

So I have implemented

```
public class JUnitTeamcityReporter extends RunListener {
    /** */
    private volatile Description suite;

    /** */
    @Override public void testRunStarted(Description desc) {
        this.suite = desc;
    }

    /** */
    @Override public void testStarted(Description desc) {
        System.out.println(String.format("##teamcity[testStarted name='%s' captureStandardOutput='true']",
            testName(suite, desc)));
    }
...
```

And I have hooked it up in my `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
    <configuration>
        <forkCount>0</forkCount>
        <properties>
            <property>
                <name>listener</name>
                <value>com.pany.JUnitTeamcityReporter</value>
            </property>
        </properties>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I run maven with `-Dtest=FirstTestSuite,SecondTestSuite`

and the output is the following:

```
[INFO] Tests run: 11, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 16.803 s - in com.pany.FirstTestSuite
# I expect that my RunListener will be notified HERE, but it does not happen!
[INFO] Running com.pany.SecondTestSuite
```

Otherwise, my solution works fine if there's just one suite per module.

Is it possible to make Surefire report every Suite properly to testRunStarted?
Unfortunately, there does not seem to be a way to get current running suite from test discription, so I don't understand how to work around this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This information is not available to JUnit, and Surefire has rather poor extension capabilities, but it can be reached:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M4</version> <!-- upgrade to M4 -->
    <configuration>
        <workingDirectory>${user.dir}</workingDirectory>
        <!-- surefire integration to intercept test suite start: -->
        <statelessTestsetInfoReporter 
            implementation="com.pany.TestSuiteAwareTestsetReporter"/>
        <properties>
            <property>
                <name>listener</name>
                <value>com.pany.JUnitTeamcityReporter</value>
            </property>
        </properties>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
    <!-- Add dependency to plugin (for surefire) as well as
    compile,test dependency to module (for junit) since they're on different classpaths -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.pany</groupId>
            <artifactId>dev-tools</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

and the code of test suite reporter:

```
public class TestSuiteAwareTestsetReporter extends SurefireStatelessTestsetInfoReporter {
    @Override public StatelessTestsetInfoConsoleReportEventListener<WrappedReportEntry, TestSetStats> createListener(
        ConsoleLogger log) {
        return new ConsoleReporter(log, false, false) {
            public void testSetStarting(TestSetReportEntry report) {
                MessageBuilder builder = MessageUtils.buffer();

                /** @see TestSetStats#concatenateWithTestGroup(MessageBuilder, ReportEntry, boolean) */
                JUnitTeamcityReporter.suite = concatenateWithTestGroup(builder, report);

                super.testSetStarting(report);
            }
        };
    }

...
```